# How to create a new folder from a variable with robocopy?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I currently have the below script:

```
set "command=robocopy"
set "params= /E /MT:12 /FP /log+:robocopy.log /TEE"
set /p cust= Please enter customer name:
set /p env= Please enter destination environment:

if %env% EQU local (
%command% "c:\code\repos\folder\%cust%" "c:\code\repos\Dest\" %params%
)
```

Which copies a subfolder between directories. The subfolder doesn't currently exist in the destination environment, what I was hoping was that robocopy would create a new folder based on the cust variable and copy files into it. What happens is that everything below the root folder is copied into the destination folder. When I try appending the cust variable to the destination address, I get the following:

2021/06/08 17:13:42 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Destination Directory c:\code\repos\Dest\folder"  \E \MT:12 \FP \log+:robocopy.log \TEE
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Am I missing something obvious?!

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the make directory command before the robocopy command.

Comment: This is wrong, `"c:\code\repos\Dest\"`, _(your backward slash is escaping the doublequote)_. It should be `"C:\code\repos\Dest"`.

Comment: Thank you all, working like a dream :)